# Websocket protocol server development

Tags: javascript, http, tcp

I am interested in building a custom Websocket server for college project. I have a good familiarity about HTTP 1.1 and knows quite well of how it works. I am asking this question assuming that Websocket clients (browsers) have their protocol specification since Websocket clients connects to Websocket server through URL begins with ws://. In addition, can Websocket server implemented without single threaded and event based environment feature of language?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess I am just going to read http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websocket servers can be implemented without single-threaded and event based environments. More than that, even such environments (like nodejs) can run multiple threads.

However, I would approach this problem using nodejs. In specific, you can use something like [Sails.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails).

It lets you develop the sort of standard APIs you know how to develop from frameworks like Ruby on Rails, ASP.NET MVC, Python Django or whatever you're coming from only you're serving directly to WebSockets (can also serve to HTTP).

Also, [socket.io](http://socket.io/) is really nice and lets you do a lot of nifty stuff on the client-side and on the server-side. That site has plenty of nice examples.

Comment: I am not going to use languages like Node.js to build this application interface. I am going to use a language designed by my professor and it does not have the websocket API yet =D

Comment: "It's a language built by my professor "?

Comment: Thank you for suggesting me about the socket.io but this project is purely about building websocket server API so I do not really need to worry about it =P